# How to find the maximum of sublists in arbitrary nested list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list `C11` containing many sublists. I want to find the maximum element of each sublist. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
C11 = [[[353.856161, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 282.754301, 0.0]], [[0.0, 294.983702, 126.991664]]]

for i in range(0,len(C11)):
    C2 = max(C11[i])
print(C2)
```

The current output is

```
[[353.856161, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 294.983702, 126.991664]]
```

The expected output is:

```
[[[353.856161],[282.754301]], [[294.983702]]]
```

Comment: Is the depth of list dimension expected to be random like that in example? If so, you'll need a solution more generalized than above

Comment: Yes the list depth will be random as shown above. It would be great to have a more generalized code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case the depth is completely arbitrary and you want to keep the same nesting structure in the output, here is a recursive function that keeps going in levels until reaching a "leaf" (list with values and not lists) and takes the `max`imums:

```py
def get_max(l):
    res = []
    if isinstance(l[0], list):
        for sub in l:
            res.append(get_max(sub))
    else:
        res.append(max(l))
    return res

print(get_max([[[353.856161, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 282.754301, 0.0]], [[0.0, 294.983702, 126.991664]]]))
```

Will give:

```
[[[353.856161], [282.754301]], [[294.983702]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this function in case the nesting-depth of the list is variable.

```py
C11=[[[353.856161, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 282.754301, 0.0]], [[0.0, 294.983702, 126.991664]]]


def find_max(ls: list) -> list:
    # does the list contain only numbers?
    if all((isinstance(x, float) for x in ls)):
        # if  yes return simple max
        return [max(ls)]
    else:
        # apply the function one level deeper
        return [find_max(x) for x in ls]

print(find_max(C11))
```

Comment: just wanted to know can this be done by iterative way??

Answer (score 1):

**List Comprehension**

**Code:-**

```
C11=[[[353.856161, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 282.754301, 0.0]], [[0.0, 294.983702, 126.991664]]]

res=[[[max(sublist)] for sublist in lis] for lis in C11]

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[[353.856161], [282.754301]], [[294.983702]]]
```

Comment: This assumes only two levels of nesting...

Comment: can you suggest what should i edit in this list comprehension.. or by list comprehension it can not be done ? @Tomerikoo

Comment: I can't think of a way using loops as you will have to literally write the loops, but you can't know in advance how many you will need... Maybe with a `while` loop somehow but then it can't be a list-comprehension

Comment: thanks for the doubt clearing.. @Tomerikoo

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick recursive generalized approach. Should work with any level of varying nesting.

```py
c11 = [[[353.856161, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 282.754301, 0.0]], [[0.0, 294.983702, 126.991664]]]

result = []

def traverse(arr, result):
    if len(arr) > 0:
        if type(arr[0]) is list:
            # check if item inside list is another list
            for i in arr:
                result = traverse(i, result)
        else:
            # if its a list of number, get the max and add it to result
            result.append(max(arr))
    return result

print(traverse(c11, result))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using recursive is the best option. Recursive works for any length of list. Used a initial validation to check if list element is empty.

**Code:**

```
check=[[[353.856161, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 282.754301, 0.0]], [[0.0, 294.983702, 126.991664]]]

def recursive_max(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    if isinstance(lst[0], list):
        min_val = []
        for val in lst:
            min_val.append(recursive_max(val))
        return min_val
    else:
        return [max(lst)]

print(recursive_max(check))
```

**Output:**

```
[[[353.856161], [282.754301]], [[294.983702]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

C11 array is multi dimension array need put in nested loop

```
C11 = [[[353.856161, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 282.754301, 0.0]], [[0.0, 294.983702, 126.991664]]]
for i in range(0, len(C11)):
    for j in range(0, len(C11[i])):
        C2 = max(C11[i][j])
        print(C2)
```

Output

[image]

Comment: This assumes only two levels of nesting...

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that the depth of the list is random.

I have used a recursive approach to replace a last-level list with a list of its maximum value.

```
def recurse(l):
    for index in range(len(l)):
        if type(l[index]) == list:
            l[index] = recurse(l[index])
        else:
            l = [max(l)]
            return l
    return l
```

Example:

```
l = [[5,3,8], [1,2,4], [[[2,4],[11,12]],[5,9]]]
recurse(l)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[8], [4], [[[4], [12]], [9]]]
```

Your Example:

```
C11=[[[353.856161, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 282.754301, 0.0]], [[0.0, 294.983702, 126.991664]]]
recurse(C11)
print(C11)
```

Output:

```
[[[353.856161], [282.754301]], [[294.983702]]]
```

Note: The function updates the list inplace so if you want to restore the list, use a copy of the old list.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
C11=[[[353.856161, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 282.754301, 0.0]], [[0.0, 294.983702, 126.991664]]]
C2=[]
for i in range(0,len(C11)):
    C2.insert(i, [])
    for j in range(0,len(C11[i])):
        C2[i].insert(j, [])
        C2[i][j].insert(0, max(C11[i][j]))
print(C2)
```

Output:

```
[[[353.856161], [282.754301]], [[294.983702]]]
```